# Viewing how Windows syscalls are handled by OS

Tags: windows, operating-system, kernel, system-calls, low-level

I am trying to figure out how syscalls are performed on kernel, Are there any good explanation about **what exactly happens on kernel, when a "syscall" instruction is encountered.** What are the ways to view those kernel-mode callbacks and **maybe** documenting some undocumented functions.

Basically what I'm asking

```
mov eax, 23h ; NtQueryVirtualMemory
syscall      ; Any way to view what OS does, how it fills registers, sets return value etc. after executing this instruction
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Viewing how Windows syscalls are handled by OS

The most important thing to understand about how system calls are handled by Windows (and how they're supposed to be handled by almost all modern operating systems) is that they are abstracted (e.g. by a library - a DLL or shared library); so that:

a) It doesn't matter if the mechanism is changed - e.g. if kernel and library internally use the `syscall` instruction or the `sysenter` instruction, or call gates or software interrupts or something else; or if different mechanisms are used on different computers (due to different CPUs supporting different features). Note that currently both Intel and AMD have proposals for future "Supervisor Entry" extensions, so it's reasonable to expect that (at some point in the future) the `syscall` instruction will be obsolete and not used.

b) It doesn't matter if the kernel is changed. E.g. if an older kernel had a specific function but the kernel designers want to replace it with a newer/better function with different parameters then they can do that, and the new library (for the new kernel) can emulate the old function so that all the old software doesn't break when the kernel (and library) is updated.

c) Whether something is a kernel system call or not becomes irrelevant. A good example of this is functions to get the current time on 80x86 - if hardware/CPU is old and doesn't support the "monotonic time stamp counter" feature then something like `QueryPerformanceCounter()` involves a system call, but on newer hardware it can be done purely in user-space by the library (avoiding the overhead of a system call completely) by relying on the `rdtsc` instruction instead.

For these reasons; Microsoft deliberated do not document the kernel's API/system calls (for any specific version of their kernel) in an attempt to prevent people from creating dodgy software that can/will break.

For assembly language programmers (especially those coming from MS-DOS) this is annoying (because calling functions in a DLL is more complex); but there isn't a good solution for that problem.

> Any way to view what OS does, how it fills registers, sets return value etc. after executing this instruction?

You could run the OS inside a virtual machine that supports debugging, and examine what it does one instruction at a time. This won't help much though (it'll be a confusing mess and different versions of the kernel may be different).

Answer (score 0):

to add a bit more info to the post above me, syscall will go into kernel at the at the syscall handler KiSystemCall64(Shadow). Here it makes a context switch and calls to the corrosponding function in the SSDT, the identifier for wich function to call is stored in EAX. To learn more about it you can consider going in kernel and hooking the syscall handler by getting the MSR register and then changing the LSTAR index of the MSR. The LSTAR points to the syscall handler. And you can overwrite it to handle it yourself / log it. Might be a fun project if you want to get to learn more about it.